# Keep floated elements in one line within table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I have table where inside one column is name and level (number) - I want name on the left side and level "sticked" to right side.
Width of columns is dynamic.
If there is enough space everything is fine, but on smaller screens it makes ugly "line breaking" - shown on image.
Does anyone have some idea how to keep everything in one line?

[image]

Structure and style (very simplified)

```
...
<td>
 <span class ="nowrap">
  <a style ="float:left;">Name</a>
  <span style ="float: right;" class ="level">10</span>
 </span>
</td>
...
```

Comment: Is there a fixed width for the table ?

Comment: [Make a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/z8krY/).

Comment: Are you columns fixed width?

Comment: width is set to 100%, content of table is loaded by ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set positive right margin to the anchor and negative left margin to the span:

```
.nowrap > a {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.nowrap > span {
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Look how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF8mh/

Answer (score 0):

Add the style to your list on the particular column with `display: inline-block;`
like

```
<td style="display:inline-block;">
    <span class="nowrap">
        <a style="float:left;">Name</a>
        <span style="float:right;" class="level">10</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Apply the style in `<td>` tag as I have done or in `<a>` tag.